# How to export to text from the crystal report viewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have vb.net 2010 and I downloaded the support pack 6 from

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

I read that this version does allow the export of text from the export button inside the crystal report viewer.  However, I can't find it in the list when I try to exporta a report.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export to text is supported in Report Document but it is not available in the viewer. If you are writing your own application you can use ReportDocument ExportToDisk. The first parameter for this methid is ExportFormatType and this is the enumeration

```
public enum ExportFormatType
{
    NoFormat = 0,
    CrystalReport = 1,
    RichText = 2,
    WordForWindows = 3,
    Excel = 4,
    PortableDocFormat = 5,
    HTML32 = 6,
    HTML40 = 7,
    ExcelRecord = 8,
    Text = 9,
    CharacterSeparatedValues = 10,
    TabSeperatedText = 11,
    EditableRTF = 12,
    Xml = 13,
    RPTR = 14,
    ExcelWorkbook = 15,
}
```